# Export Models and use it on template

Tags: typescript, types, model, sequelize.js

I have a model definition in file **user.ts**

```
export default class User extends Model {
  public id?: string;
   ...

  public static setup(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
   ...
  }

  public static association(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I import it in an **index.ts** file to export to other locations

```
export const models = {
  Address,
   ...
  User,
};
```

I am trying to use the **models.User** class in a Template, I tried the following ways, and haven`t got it working

**1.**

```
import Repository from '../../types/Repository';
import { models } from '../../models';

const { User } = models;

export default class UserRepository extends Repository<User> { // <- TS2749: 'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof User'?

}
```

**2.**

```
import Repository from '../../types/Repository';
import { models } from '../../models';


export default class UserRepository extends Repository<models.User> { // <- TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'models'.

}
```

The **Repository** class has the following shape:

```
export default class Repository<T extends Sequelize.Model> {
 ...
}
```

--- EDIT ---

**3. (pointed by MBB)**

```
import Repository from '../../types/Repository';
import { models } from '../../models';

const { User } = models;

export default class UserRepository extends Repository<typeof User> { // <- TS2344: Type 'typeof User' does not satisfy the constraint 'Model<any, any>'.   Type 'typeof User' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<any, any>': _attributes, _creationAttributes, isNewRecord, where, and 16 more.

}
```

---

How can I use/export these models to use it within a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the first case** you are assigning the `class User` to the `Generic T` of the `Repository` class, which will not work as the class *will not* be converted to `type` in typescript in this scenario.

*To illustrate* when you use a `class` or assign a variable with `class` then you are actually get back is the `constructor function` which is not a `type`.

For example  -

```
class A {
    name: string = "A"
}

let b = A;
console.log(b);
```

with ES5 target this will produce below log  -

```
 ƒ A() {
     this.name = "A";
 }
```

As your Repository class is expecting a type `<T>` you have to use the `typeof` operator:

```
export default class UserRepository extends Repository<typeof User> { 
}
```

**In the second case**  the exports of a module are returned as a special `module namespace object`. So you cannot use them like the way you are using (`modules.User`). But you can assign it to a variable and use it, which you did in the below line -

```
const { User } = models;
```

For more information on the class you can [`refer the link`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions) -

Comment: I tried to use `typeOf User` as well, I forgot to add the case on my question, but I got the error "TS2344: Type 'typeof User' does not satisfy the constraint 'Model<any, any>'.   Type 'typeof User' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<any, any>': _attributes, _creationAttributes, isNewRecord, where, and 16 more."